# How can I render a template depending on what's inside a column of a table using Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, conditional-statements

Here's my view that renders a template that shows a button when the article has a specific tag to it.

```
  <% if article.display_button? %>
    <% reaction = Reaction.find_by(article_base_id: article.id) %>
    <%= render partial: '**', locals: { article: article, reaction: reaction } %>
  <% end %>
```

I would like to render the template when the article has a specific tag to it AND the column "tie-up" of the table "article_bases" equals 0. (article_bases table stores all the articles).

I tried these below, but I have the feeling that this isn't right.

```
<% if article.display_button? && ArticleBase.exists?(tie_up: 0) %>
```

Please help!

P.S.
'article' is defined as below in my articles_controller.

```
@article = ArticleBase.published.site(params[:site]).find(params[:id])
```

It belongs to the model article_base.rb, and there is a column 'tie_up' which stores either 0 or 1.

articles_controller:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
    def show
      raise NotFound if params[:page].to_i > @article.page_count(device)
      @article_tie_up_excluded = ArticleBase.exclude_tie_up
    end

    def headline
      @article = ArticleBase.published.site(params[:site]).find(params[:id])
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render_404 }
        format.json { render 'front/common/articles/show' }
      end
    end
```

Comment: Can you put your article model? and also your tag model

Comment: What you have there says 'if the given article has ``display_button`` set to true and *any record* of ``ArticleBase`` has ``tie_up`` equal to 0'. That seems unlikely to be what you mean. What type of model is ``article``? Is it an ``ArticleBase`` or something that has an association to ``ArticleBase``?

Comment: Thank you for your advice!
article is defined as below in my articles_controller.
@article = ArticleBase.published.site(params[:site]).find(params[:id])

And "article" belongs to article_base.rb model.

Comment: I think you want `<% if article.display_button? && article.article_base.tie_up == 0) %>`

Comment: `AND the column "tie-up" of the table "article_bases" equals 0.`
I think this might your misunderstanding. The _table_ does have _any_ value for "tie up". Individual _records_ do.

Comment: How can I render a template when the individual record (the 'article') has 0 in the tie_up column?